# How to create a new binary variable based on another binary variable in a data frame with the function mutate in R?

Tags: r

The data frame df has 2 variables---the 1st column is id, and the 2nd column is ladies' English proficiency (lep).
Now, I want to create a new column called sign with the rule----if there are zero(s) between the 1st 1 and the last 1 in lep variable, then sign=1, otherwise sign=0. Any helps will be appreciated!

```
structure(list(id = c(3831001, 3831001, 3831001, 3831001, 3831001, 
3831001, 3831001, 3831001, 3831002, 3831002, 3831002, 3831002, 
3831002, 3831002, 3831002, 3831002, 3831003, 3831003, 3831003, 
3831003, 3831003, 3831003, 3831003, 3831003, 3831004, 3831004, 
3831004, 3831004, 3831004, 3831004, 3831005, 3831005, 3831005, 
3831005, 3831005, 3831005, 3831005, 3831006, 3831006, 3831006, 
3831006, 3831006, 3831006, 3831007, 3831007, 3831007, 3831007, 
3831007, 3831007, 3831007, 3831007), lep = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
0, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 
1, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), groups = structure(list(
    id = c(3831001, 3831002, 3831003, 3831004, 3831005, 3831006, 
    3831007), .rows = structure(list(1:8, 9:16, 17:24, 25:30, 
        31:37, 38:43, 44:51), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))->df

#.The expected result is as follows,
id        lep sign

3831001    1   0

3831001    1   0

3831001    1   0

3831001    NA  0

3831001    NA  0

3831001    0   0

3831001    NA  0

3831001    0   0

3831002    1   1

3831002    0   1

3831002    0   1

3831002    1   1

3831002    0   1

3831002    0   1

3831002    NA  1

3831002    1   1

...............

3831006    1   0

3831006    0   0

3831006    NA  0

3831006    0   0

3831006    0   0

3831006    0   0

3831007    1   1

3831007    0   1

3831007    0   1

3831007    0   1

3831007    0   1

3831007    NA  1

3831007    NA  1

3831007    1   1
```

Comment: I am satisfied with both answers. However, it seems that there is only one choice among all candiates and made the question raiser very awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), grouped by 'id' , get the position index of the logical vector (`lep == 1`) with `which`, then the min and max of the positions got from `range`, get a sequence (`:`) between those within `Reduce`, get the corresponding 'lep' values by using that as index, check if there any 0 `%in%` that, convert to integer (`+`) and assign (`:=`) it to 'sign' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, # // convert to data.table
    sign :=  # // assign to new column
         +( # // coerce logical to binary
           0 %in% # // check if 0 is there in the subset of lep
             lep[ # // extract the lep elements based on index
                Reduce(`:`, # // get the sequence 
                   range( # // returns the min and max of position index
                        which(lep == 1) # // returns the position index
                   ))]),
               by = id] # // grouped by ID
df
#         id lep sign
# 1: 3831001   1    0
# 2: 3831001   1    0
# 3: 3831001   1    0
# 4: 3831001  NA    0
# 5: 3831001  NA    0
# 6: 3831001   0    0
# 7: 3831001  NA    0
# 8: 3831001   0    0
# 9: 3831002   1    1
#10: 3831002   1    1
#11: 3831002   0    1
#12: 3831002   1    1
#13: 3831002   0    1
#14: 3831002   0    1
#15: 3831002  NA    1
#16: 3831002   1    1
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For each `id`, you can get `max` and `min` index where `lep = 1` and return 1 if any of the value is 0 between them.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(sign = {inds <- which(lep == 1);
                 as.integer(any(lep[min(inds):max(inds)] == 0))})

#       id   lep  year  flag  sign
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 3831001     1     1     0     0
# 2 3831001     1     2     0     0
# 3 3831001     1     3     1     0
# 4 3831001    NA     4     0     0
# 5 3831001    NA     5     0     0
# 6 3831001     0     6     0     0
# 7 3831001    NA     7     0     0
# 8 3831001     0     8     0     0
# 9 3831002     1     1     0     1
#10 3831002     1     2     0     1
# … with 41 more rows
```